# Metodo for no muestra imagenes en array

Tags: javascript, array

Consulta, ¿por que al momento de mostrar imágenes con este método **for**, muestra solo el array "**Colección.push**" pero **no puedo mostrar** el array "**imagenes**" con el mismo **metodo for** cambiando el parametro del **for** (var objetos of **coleccion**) por el **for** (var objetos of **imagenes**)?.

No me arroja **ningún error en consola** pero no muestra nada una vez cambio **imagenes** por **coleccion**.

**Saludos y muchas gracias!**

```
var imagenes=[];
imagenes["Cauchin"]="vaca.png";
imagenes["Pocacho"]="pollo.png";
imagenes["Tocinaurio"]="cerdo.png";

var coleccion=[];
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Pocacho",100,30));
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Tocinaurio",150,70));
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Cauchin",50,40));

for (var objetos of coleccion)
{
console.log(objetos);
objetos.mostrar();
}
 class Pakiman
{
constructor(n,v,a)
{
    this.imagen= new Image();
    this.nombre=n;
    this.vida=v;
    this.ataque=a;
    this.imagen.src=imagenes[this.nombre];
}
hablar()
{
    document.writeln(this.nombre+" <strong>dice</strong>: 
"+this.nombre+"..."+this.nombre+"<br/>")
}
mostrar()
{
    document.body.appendChild(this.imagen);
    document.writeln("<br/>"+"<strong>Nombre: </strong>"+this.nombre+" 
<br/>"+"<strong>Vida: </strong>"+this.vida+"<br/>"+"<strong>Ataque: 
</strong>"+this.ataque+"<br/>");
}
}
```

Con el parametro 
    for (var objetos of **coleccion**)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el parametro 
    for (var objetos of **imagenes**)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para poder ayudarte mejor debes decir / mostrar en la pregunta lo que es `objetos`  y lo que hace el método `mostrar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tienes es que el array **imagenes** lo quieres colocar como un array **asociativo**, es decir un array cuyos índices no son numéricos sinó cadenas de texto, claves. Si quieres hacer un array asociativo tienes que hacer un array tipo **json** como te mostraré a continuación:

```js
var imagenes=[];
imagenes["Cauchin"]="vaca.png";
imagenes["Pocacho"]="pollo.png";
imagenes["Tocinaurio"]="cerdo.png";

console.log(imagenes);

var imagenes = [];
imagenes.push("vaca.png");
imagenes.push("pollo.png");
imagenes.push("cerdo.png");

console.log(imagenes);

var imagenes = [{Cauchin: "vaca.png"},{Pocacho: "pollo.png"},{Tocinaurio: "cerdo.png"}];

console.log(imagenes);
```

Si te fijas el primero es como quisiste hacerlo, el segundo es como te debería de funcionar y el tercero es como en realidad tu lo quieres donde se utilizan llaves `{}` para generar el array de elementos **clave:valor**.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso del arreglo "imagenes" estas tratando el arreglo como un objeto. El arreglo imagenes en este caso tiene longitud 0 y tiene los 3 elementos como propiedades del objeto imagenes. para recorrer las propiedades del objeto puedes hacerlo con un 'for in'

```
for (var propiedad in imagenes)
{
    console.log(propiedad);
    console.log(imagenes[propiedad]);
}
```